# binary structure of a Word file

Tags: ms-word, doc, hex-editors

I'm looking for tutorials that help me understand the binary structure of a Word file; a detailed analysis of the structure (the header block of the file, the other block, their beginning, their purpose etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the specs:

[Microsoft Office Word 97-2007. Binary File Format (.doc)](https://download.microsoft.com/download/0/B/E/0BE8BDD7-E5E8-422A-ABFD-4342ED7AD886/Word97-2007BinaryFileFormat(doc)Specification.pdf)

[Word (.doc) Binary File Format (Microsoft Word 97, Microsoft Word 2000, Microsoft Word 2002, and Microsoft Office Word 2003)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc313153(v=office.12).aspx)